# async function doesn't seem to run inside sync code

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

im trying to make a command that connects to the database, i created a little CLI script that loops through files in specific folders to get command class modules

my problem is that in one of my commands, i'm trying to connect to sequelize, and it just doesn't seem to be doing anything. i get no output to the console, nor does it even seem to try to connect

this is probably because i'm still kind of struggling to figure out how to properly do sync / async / await stuff...notice how i use `glob.sync` cause i want to loop through the files sychronously, but then in my command i need to connect to the database using `await`

`cli.js`:

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node

const patterns = [
    './node_modules/unity/src/commands/**/*.js',
    './src/commands/**/*.js',
]
const glob = require('glob')
const path = require('path')
const yargs = require('yargs')
const signature = yargs.argv._[0]
const process = require('process')

patterns.forEach(pattern => {
    glob.sync(pattern).forEach(file => {
        const commandPath = path.resolve(file)
        const command = require(commandPath)

        if (command.signature == signature) {
            command.argv = yargs.argv
            command.run()

            process.exit()
        }
    })
})

console.log('Command not found.')
```

here is an example command in one of the `commands` folders:

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')

class MigrateCommand {
    static signature = 'migrate'
    static argv = {}

    static run() {
        const sequelize = new Sequelize({
            dialect: 'mysql',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3306,
            database: 'dio_unity2',
            username: 'root',
            password: '',
        })

        const connect = async () => {
            try {
                await sequelize.authenticate()
                console.log('Connection successful.')
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Unable to connect.', error)
            }
        }

        connect()

        console.log('migrate run complete')
    }
}

module.exports = MigrateCommand
```

i've set npx up so i can just run `npx unity migrate` and it will call this command based on the `migrate` signature

now my console should say `connection successful` or `unable to connect` and then `migrate run complete`, but all i see in the console is `migrate run complete`. it's like it isn't even trying to connect at all...

i have no idea what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This is closely related to [*How do I return the result of an asynchronous call?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but we can do better in terms of answering this specific question than closing it as a duplicate of that, since the OP doesn't actually need to make the code synchronous.

Comment: Why do you do `process.exit()` after a single successful run? That will ignore all files but the first...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because if a command was found via the signature, then we know that this is the command that was intended to be run, therefore we do not need to check for any other commands.

Comment: Got it. I thought you wanted to do each of them one at a time, not just the first you found.

Comment: yeah i basically just wanted to loop through all files in the directories, once a class was found with a particular signature, it doesn't need to keep iterating through the files. hope that made sense. still very new to the JS world of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You **can't** make an asynchronous process synchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) without spawning a new thread and synchronously waiting on it. (There's an `npm` package that does that, via [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options).)

But the good news here is **there's no need to** in your code. You want to do things *in series*, but doing things *in series* isn't quite the same as doing them *synchronously*. Here's how:

First, `run` can't make the async process it's starting via `authenticate` synchronous. So instead, `run` should just be `async` (and we don't need `connect`):

```
static async run() {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        database: 'dio_unity2',
        username: 'root',
        password: '',
    })

    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate()
        console.log('Connection successful.')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect.', error)
    }

    console.log('migrate run complete')
}
```

Next, in the script, we loop through your patterns and files using an `async` function:

```
(async () => {
    for (const pattern of patterns) {
        for (const file of glob.sync(pattern)) {
            const commandPath = path.resolve(file)
            const command = require(commandPath)

            if (command.signature == signature) {
                command.argv = yargs.argv
                await command.run() // *** Note the `await`
                process.exit()
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Command not found.")
})();
```

That does the work asynchronously, but one after another (in series).

---

If it were me, I wouldn't use `process.exit()` to terminate the process, it's a very aggressive form of process termination which may prevent some things from finishing ([details here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processexitcode)), and may not be as clear to people doing code maintenance later as alternatives.. Now that we've put the code in a wrapper function, I'd just return out of the function to break the loops:

```
await command.run();
return;
```

Comment: noting that the OP states that "one of my commands ....", implying that only one has asynchrony, it may be useful to mention that `await command.run()` runs perfectly OK regardless if command.run is async or not

Comment: @Bravo removing `async` from the `run` function of the class doesn't work. TJ's answer works perfectly, however.

Comment: @kjdion84 - Bravo wasn't suggesting that. They were pointing out that **if** you had a `run` that wasn't `async`, it would still be fine to do `await command.run()`.

Comment: @kjdion84 - I understood, based on your question, that you only have one async "command", implies the others are not - I was pointing out that the `await` works identically for those ... no part of my comment even hinted that you can remove the `await` - perhaps you already knew that `await` works like this (though not likely), I made the comment for others facing similar issues

Comment: @Bravo oh gotcha